# AppleScript forgets UI element of Chrome exists after its restart. Gets weirdly fixed, need proper solution

Tags: macos, applescript, google-chrome

I made 3 scripts to switch between certain browser widths in Chrome’s developer mode. The plan is to click those scripts in my Dock so Chrome enters developer mode (DevTools) and sets needed widths. Or just sets them straightaway if DevTools is already open.
The idea is to have 1-click solution and still to be able to correct the width manually after quick switching (which isn’t an option if using presets).

[image: Chrome DevTools Width text field]

The problem was to find this little text field in GUI, the Accessibility Inspector wasn’t helpful for me here, so after googling and GUI parsing I managed to find it’s deep location.

**And those scripts kinda work. But!**

When Chrome restarts the scripts break and act as if they forget DevTools exists and cannot click the field. And the weird solution is to launch Accessibility Inspector and to target and click the field. After this ritual the DevTools UI element starts to be findable again.
What I tried is to launch DevTools after Chrome restarts (thinking it needs to have a first manual launch or smth), but only the method above works.

Can you help me find the way so it just works? The code for 1 of the scripts is below. Thank you!

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    
    set delayShort to "0.2"
    set delayLong to "0.5"
    
    
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Chrome"
            
            set frontmost to true
            set browserWidth to 735
            
            
            try
                
                if not (exists UI element "DevTools" of group 1 of window 1) then
                    
                    keystroke "i" using {command down, option down}
                    delay delayLong
                    
                else
                end if
                
                delay delayShort
                
                click text field 1 of group 1 of group 2 of group 1 of group 1 of group 1 of group 1 of group 1 of group 1 of group 1 of group 1 of UI element "DevTools" of group 1 of window 1
                delay delayShort
                keystroke browserWidth
                keystroke return
                
            end try
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

(BigSur 11.6 (20G165), Chrome 94.0.4606.61, DevTools is docked to the right)

Comment: What version of **macOS** are you running? What version of **Google Chrome** are you running? What layout orientation are you using for **Developer Tools**, Undock into separate window, Dock to left, Dock to bottom, or Dock to right? This missing information is important to accurately troubleshoot/debug the _code_ and or issues you are having.

Comment: Sorry!

BigSur 11.6 (20G165),
Chrome 94.0.4606.61,

DevTools is docked to the right

Comment: **UI Scripting** is _kludgy_ at best and prone to failure for a number of reasons. Having it report that `exists UI element "DevTools" of group 1 of window 1` is `false` when it's clearly visible on the screen and then in another instance report `true` is the very reason to avoid **UI Scripting** if at all possible. I played with it a bit to try and establish a pattern but it will take more time than I have to give to, sorry.

Comment: One thing I did notice is the if it returned `false` and then I moused-over it while **Accessibility Inspector** was running it would then return `true`. Its as though **Google Chrome** is not enumerating or exposing everything until an _application_ that can examine its _hierarchical **UI element** structure_ like **Accessibility Inspector** does, it then exposes it to **AppleScript**.

Comment: @user3439894 Yes that's weird. Thanks anyway!
I was thinking about getting to this Width text field in a different way but ended up not knowing how would I do that at all :)

Comment: Under the circumstances, here's my reworked version of your _script_ that opens **Accessibility Inspector** and tucks it as far as it can in the lower right of the **Desktop**, while using the _third-party utility_ [**cliclick**](https://github.com/BlueM/cliclick) to move the **mouse** just over the top right corner of the _window_ in **Google Chrome** so `UI element "DevTools"` is available. It also sets the `bounds` of the window so it's predictable, otherwise addition coding would be necessary to calculate where the _window_ is. See this [example AppleScript code](https://paste.ee/p/tdWHX).

Comment: @user3439894 Wow, thank you so much!

Comment: If that works for you, let me know so I can post a proper answer, thanks.